# How to use a library ported for Native Client(NaCl)?

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, openssl, google-nativeclient

I was looking at the list of [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) for ported libraries and I want to use openssl for my native client extention. I can't find a proper instruction set to install these ported libraries, I downloaded the openssl compressed file and followed the instructions given in INSTALL file but that encountered some errors which I can't resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To install a library ported to Native Client as part of `naclports` you'll need to:

- Download and install the NaCl SDK:
  https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/sdk/download
- Set `NACL_SDK_ROOT` in your environment to point at the `pepper_*` version under the location you install it at.

  You may want to explicitly install the very latest version: `pepper_canary`, with: `./naclsdk install pepper_canary`
- Sync the `naclports` repository: [Checkout guide](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/HowTo_Checkout)

  Check out a branch that matches you SDK, or master for `pepper_canary`
- To build `openssl`, do something like this:

  ```
    ./bin/naclports --force --from-source install openssl
  ```

  If you have no local modifications you can drop the `--force` and `--from-source` flags

  This will build the `newlib` NaCl version by default.

  You can set `TOOLCHAIN` in the environment to: `glibc` / `pnacl` / `newlib` to select an explicit version.

The library will then be installed into your SDK.

Comment: After the `git checkout -b pepper_41 origin/pepper_41` step on executing `gclient sync` I get this error: 
`src (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
_____ src at refs/remotes/origin/master
----------------------------------------
Error: 1> Could not switch upstream branch from refs/remotes/origin/pepper_41 to refs/remotes/origin/master
1> Please use --force or merge or rebase manually:
1> cd /home/kunal/Downloads/naclports/src; git rebase refs/remotes/origin/master
1> OR git checkout -b <some new branch> refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: Ok i figured out that we need not do `gclient sync` after checking out the branch