# Link openssl ported library with Native Client(NaCl) Module?

Tags: encryption, google-chrome-extension, openssl, google-nativeclient

I am developing a simple chrome extension to encrypt data and upload it to dropbox. I built the openssl library on the link [naclports](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/PortList) to use in my NaCl module. My makefile is posted on [codeshare link](http://www.codeshare.io/SqkdG). The code is not able to locate the openssl header files, it reports errors as follows:

```
  CXX  pnacl/Release/crest.o
In file included from crest.cc:17:
./aes.h:4:10: fatal error: 'openssl/conf.h' file not found
#include <openssl/conf.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [pnacl/Release/crest.o] Error 1
```

For reference I am also posting links to my sources files:
[aes.h header file](http://www.codeshare.io/4KFQZ), [aes.c code](http://www.codeshare.io/upbOl), [crest.cc](http://www.codeshare.io/AKjIj)

Comment: Most likely you didn't build openssl with TOOLCHAIN=pnacl, but you are attempting to build your app/example with pnacl.

Comment: @sbc yeah you are right my building with TOOLCHAIN=pnacl had failed, I have posted another question regarding that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192824/openssl-native-client-port-gives-error-on-building) which you already commented upon. Thanks

Comment: A JS interface for Native encryption would be tremendously helpful to me. If you make your work available for others please let me know where to find it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to be sure that the header can be found in your include path.
If built correctly, openssl's headers will go here:
${NACL_SDK_ROOT}/toolchain/linux_pnacl/le32-nacl/usr/include/openssl/conf.h

You'll likely want to add something like this to the compile command line:
-I ${NACL_SDK_ROOT}/toolchain/linux_pnacl/le32-nacl/usr/include

Comment: I followed the instructions in your previous answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148430/how-to-use-a-library-ported-for-native-clientnacl to install openssl which succeeded but I can't find the files in the given include path

Comment: I found the openssl header files in this path `$NACL_SDK_ROOT/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/x86_64-nacl/usr/include/openssl`. Does this mean openssl is not correctly installed ?

Comment: As mentioned in the README.rst file I used the `./make_all.sh openssl` command but that failed for `i686/glibc/release` after successfully installing `x86_64/glibc/release`  and `x86_64/newlib/release`