# Openssl native client port gives error on building

Tags: google-chrome-extension, openssl, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-nativeclient

I am working on a simple chrome NaCl extension where I want to use the openssl library for encryption of data. I checked out the pepper_40 branch of naclports as described on the [wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/HowTo_Checkout) and tried to build the port for openssl but it is encountered with the following error.

```
kunal@Baweja:~/Downloads/naclports/src$ ./make_all.sh openssl
+ set -e
+ TARGETS=openssl
+ TARGETS=openssl
+ BUILD_FLAGS=--ignore-disabled
+ export TOOLCHAIN
+ export NACL_ARCH
+ export BUILD_FLAGS
+ NACL_ARCH=x86_64
+ TOOLCHAIN=glibc
+ make openssl
bin/naclports install openssl --ignore-disabled
Already installed 'openssl' [x86_64/glibc/release] 
+ TOOLCHAIN=newlib
+ make openssl
bin/naclports install openssl --ignore-disabled
Building 'glibc-compat' [x86_64/newlib/release] 
naclports: Building glibc-compat: failed.
make: *** [openssl] Error 1
```

What could be the possible error exactly and any ways around that ?

Comment: To see more information on the failure you can run the same command with VERBOSE=1 (in recent versions this is shown by default on failures).

Comment: @sbc here is the error pointed to by VERBOSE=1 option. `/home/kunal/Downloads/nacl_sdk/pepper_41/tools/sel_ldr_x86_32: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
naclports: Building openssl: failed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @sbc for telling me about VERBOSE=1 option in the comment on the above question. I identified that the libstdc++.so.6 file was missing while accessing `from $NACL_SDK_ROOT/tools/sel_ldr_x86_32`. This is so because my machine is of x86_64 type i.e. 64 bit. Hence we need to install `libstdc++` for 32 bit machines separatly by using the command `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

The original solution to missing `libstdc++.so.6` file is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471722/libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)